# Is there a way to conditionally disable openidConnectClient and instead use LDAP authentication using ldapRegistry in OpenLiberty?

Tags: open-liberty

I am configuring a OpenLiberty server.xml file. I have currently two versions of the server.xml file, one which has the openidConnectClient which helps me authenticate the user with SSO, and another which helps me authenticate the user with LDAP registry.

I would like to have an ability to decide to use only openidConnectClient or only LDAP registry based on the value of environment variable.

Is this possible?

I tried providing if condition in the server.xml, however that did not work.
`<if test="${DISABLE_OPENID == 'true'}">`